# visual studio 2019 for wxWidgets: link problem

Tags: c++, visual-studio, wxwidgets

I'm trying to follow what I saw [here](https://computingonplains.wordpress.com/creating-wxwidgets-programs-with-visual-studio-2017-part-1/):
I start off by creating an "Empty project" and use just two source files as indicated in the link.
I also use the wwwidgets.props file to make the properties of my project conformant.
Unfortunately there is a huge list of warnings on compilation, but worst of all, an error which says that `LNK2019  unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)`
This sounds like I've used a bad compilation option, but which?

Comment: Do you have a `main`, though? :)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you've created a new console project rather than a new GUI ("Windows") project, check the "Linker|System|SubSystem" option in the properties dialog.

As for the warnings, you should really should at least a couple of them to give us a fighting chance of figuring out where do they come from.

Comment: OK, I followed your advice and created a new Windows project, used the wxwidgets.props file to configure the project. I removed most of the "boiler plate" files that the wizard created for me and put in the files suggested by the article I referred to in my question. Compilation and linking and execution then succeeded. Although this is a "solution", it does pass by the step of removing all that unnecessary code, unlike what the article I referred to suggested. But now I have my original and the one based on your suggestion. I'll do a diff of the command lines.

Comment: You can create an empty GUI project too, this is just not the default, you have to explicitly check the checkbox in the project creation wizard.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty console project for this but you must apply the following modifications: follow VZ's advice and change the Linker|System|Subsystem option to Windows, for all the configurations (Release and Debug). I also changed the C++ preprocessor macro from _CONSOLE to _WINDOWS
and I applied the wxwidgets.props file with the Property manager.

Actually I had asked an almost identical questions a few months back, was very unwell in the meantime and came back forgetting the post.